# Using cross validation for calculating a ridge regression parameter

Tags: r

I've got a 57 feature (column) ~4600 row dataset within a dataframe. I'd like to perform 10-fold cross validation on it for the purposes of calculating a good ridge regression parameter.  Could somebody show me how to do this in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ridge.cv()`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/parcor/docs/ridge.cv) in the `parcor` package is designed for just the purpose.

Here is an example taken from the manual:

```
> n<-100 # number of observations
> p<-60 # number of variables
> X<-matrix(rnorm(n*p),ncol=p) 
> y<-rnorm(n)
> ridge.object<-ridge.cv(X,y)
> ridge.object
$intercept

0.01146743 

$coefficients
           X1            X2            X3            X4            X5            X6            X7           
 1.709387e-02  4.833916e-03  3.954463e-03 -9.671448e-03  4.507962e-03 -6.370366e-03 -4.655737e-02  
...
          X57           X58           X59           X60 
-2.119606e-03 -1.229390e-04 -1.912877e-03 -1.833788e-02 

$lambda.opt
[1] 540
```

Here, `$lambda.opt` is the optimal value of the regularization parameter obtained using ten-fold cross-validation.